# Socket.io app not working on other devices when ran from server

Tags: websocket, server, socket.io, device

I have built a socket.io app which I have ran continously using the forever command from SSH.

I am a university student and I have done this in the university. I can go onto the website / socket.io app using any computer in the university, however I cannot use my mobile phone or personal computer to access the site.

When I try and access the site, it takes about a minute to try and access the site, but then it just says "this site cannot be reached".

Is there a way I can access the site from any device? As I said, the script is running continously so there is no issue with that...

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your server is not on the public internet.  Instead, it's on your university network and when you get on a device that tries to access it from the public internet, then the university firewalls won't allow it to be reached and/or the IP address you are using to access the server is not a public IP address.

When on the university network (as WiFi, for example), some universities also have multiple classes of devices on the network.  Some are allowed to access any resources on the network.  Others are only allowed to access public resources on the university network or resources on the internet.  It could be that the computers in the university have the right privileges and it could be that your mobile phone or laptop do not, even if they are on the university WiFi.

Though there are several different ways to fix this, the usual approach is to deploy your server outside the university network in a place that it can be accessed from anywhere on the public internet (typically a hosting provider that supports the features your server needs).  And, to reach your server, you would set up a DNS entry such as myplayserver.com that points at the public IP address of your server.